# How to compare two arrays? And get the element which are not in the other one?

Tags: ios, swift

Let say we have two arrays:

```
var a = ["Tom", "Harry", "jim", "Allen"]
var b = ["Tom", "Harry", "jim", "Allen", "Chloe", "Jasmine"]
```

now i want an array which will have the following elements in it:

```
var requiredArray = ["Chloe","Jasmine"]
```

Comment: You need to make some attempt before asking for help.  Can you show the code that you have tried?

Comment: i could not find it on internet. :/ Don't know the syntax

Comment: Even a naive attempt that simply iterated the arrays would be something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your spec is insufficiently specific, but this is one easy way:

```
var a = ["Tom", "Harry", "jim", "Allen"]
var b = ["Tom", "Harry", "jim", "Allen", "Chloe", "Jasmine"]
let c = Array(Set(b).subtract(a))
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way is to use `filter` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FPSs12SequenceType6filteruRq_S__Fq_FFqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSbGSaqqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7Element_)):

```
  let result = b.filter { !a.contains($0) }
```